# Migrating from MongoDB to PostgreSQL: Writing aggregation pipeline query for PostgreSQL

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, aggregation-framework

We have a requirement of migrating from MongoDB to PostgreSQL in our Node.js application. Our express APIs heavily use mongodb `aggregation` framework, which we have to re-write in PostgreSQL. For Example, we have below form of data:

```
[{
    "product": "PD1",
    "application": "A",
    "project": "PR1",
    "version": "1"
},{
    "product": "PD1",
    "application": "A",
    "project": "PR2",
    "version": "3"
},{
    "product": "PD1",
    "application": "B",
    "project": "PR3",
    "version": "2"
},{
    "product": "PD2",
    "application": "C",
    "project": "PR4",
    "version": "5"
},{
    "product": "PD2",
    "application": "C",
    "project": "PR5",
    "version": "2"
}]
```

It is guaranteed that an application belongs to only one product. Similarly, a project belongs to only one application. I have written below MongoDB aggregate query to summarize this data:

```
let data = await CompanyModel.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        "_id": "$application",
        "projects":{
            $push: {
                "project": "$project",
                "version": "$version"
            }
        },
        "product": {$first: "$product"}
    }
},{
    $group: {
        "_id": "$product",
        "applications":{
            $push: {
                "application": "$_id",
                "projects": "$projects"
            }
        },
    }
}])
```

The above query outputs below result:

```
[{
    "_id": "PD2",
    "applications": [{
        "application": "C",
        "projects": [{ "project": "PR4", "version": "5" }, { "project": "PR5", "version": "2" }]
    }]
},
{
    "_id": "PD1",
    "applications": [{
        "application": "B",
        "projects": [{ "project": "PR3", "version": "2" }]
    }, { "application": "A", "projects": [{ "project": "PR1", "version": "1" }, { "project": "PR2", "version": "3" }] }]
}]
```

There is some hard requirement to structure data in this way only.

Now comes the main part, how do we write a query in PostgreSQL that acts like a pipeline just like above query, where output of one stage is input to other stage. I have some experience with SQL but have never worked on PostgreSQL. But I know that PostgreSQL supports JSON data. My guess is that in SQl, I would do something like below:

```
SELECT * from (SELECT * from table_name group by field_name1) group by field_name2;
```

Basically I am trying to check if any such pipeline feature exist in PostgreSQL but couldn't find any.

I need some guidance on this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH app_projects AS (
  SELECT 
    application,
    product,
    jsonb_agg(
      jsonb_build_object(
        'project', project, 
        'version', version
      )
    ) AS projects
  FROM 
    CompanyTable
  GROUP BY 
    application, 
    product
),
prod_apps AS (
  SELECT 
    product,
    jsonb_agg(
      jsonb_build_object(
        'application', application, 
        'projects', projects
      )
    ) AS applications
  FROM 
    app_projects
  GROUP BY 
    product
)
SELECT 
  product AS _id,
  applications
FROM 
  prod_apps;
```

I used here CTE in postgresql. You can read more here, good explanation:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-cte/

1. In `app_projects` CTE, for each `application` and `product`, I group projects and versions into a json array of objects using the `jsonb_agg` and `jsonb_build_object` functions.
2. In `prod_apps` CTE, I group the results of the previous CTE by `product` and create a json array of objects for each product containing `applications` and their `projects`.

At the end, I select all the results from the `prod_apps` CTE to get the desired output.

`jsonb_build_object` - it's a function

```
jsonb_build_object(
    'project', project, 
    'version', version
)
```

workes like this:

```
{'project': project, 'version': version}
```

`jsonb_agg` - it's an expression
if you have `some_value`:

```
some_value
------
1
2
3
```

`jsonb_agg(some_value)` will make:

```
jsonb_agg
---------
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please explain your answer a bit for better understanding of the query?

Comment: @Kanojian sorry :) I forgot about this. Updated answer.

Comment: @Kanojian does it make sence?